# reading JSON files in CLOUDANT database

Tags: cloudant

I wrote a parser in python  to convert my log file into JSON format.

Now I am trying to save the JSON files into a Cloudant data base.

I am not sure, how can it be done? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can I confirm that you are asking how to save your JSON data to Cloudant?

Comment: yes Chris...I want this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this basic script as a starting point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests

cl_username = "username"
cl_password = "password"
cl_database = "database"

json = open("yourfile.json", 'r')

response = requests.post(
    "https://" + cl_username + ".cloudant.com/" + cl_database,
    data=json,
    auth=(cl_username, cl_password),
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
)

if response.status_code == 200:
   print "OK:\n" + response.json()
else:
   print "ERROR:\n" + response.text
```